# why is getAttributeNS returning null?

Tags: javascript, svg

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('test'),
    use = svg.lastElementChild;

alert(use.getAttributeNS(null, 'x'));
// "200"

alert(use.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href'));
// "#shape"

alert(use.getAttributeNS('http://foo.io/bar', 'foo'));  
// null - why?
```

```html
<svg id="test"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:test="http://foo.io/bar">
    <defs>
        <g id="shape">
            <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#shape" x="200" y="50" test:foo="bar" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the MDN page it would appear that namespaces are not supported in html5 documents - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttributeNS#Example

Looks like you'll have to use `use.getAttribute('test:foo');`

Comment: thank you.  I completely missed that in the examples section.  I think I was thrown off because it's working for specific namespaces (namely `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`)